# Why does using nested traits change PHP behavior?

Tags: php, traits

Using PHP 7.2, I have a class `MyClass` that uses a trait `MyFirstTrait`. It is defined like this:

```
class MyClass
{
    use MyFirstTrait;
}
```

This `MyFirstTrait` uses another trait `MySecondTrait`. It is defined like this:

```
trait MyFirstTrait
{
    use MySecondTrait;
}
```

`MySecondTrait` does not use any other traits. It is defined like this:

```
trait MySecondTrait
{
}
```

If I define `MyClass` first and then the traits (it does not matter in which order the traits are defined), an error is raised.

The file would be like:

```
// Not working
class MyClass { use MyFirstTrait; }

// These two lines can be swapped, the result is the same.
trait MyFirstTrait { use MySecondTrait; }
trait MySecondTrait { }
```

And the error raised is this:

```
Fatal error: Trait 'MyFirstTrait' not found in …
```

However, if I remove the nesting and remove the `use` clause from `MyFirstTrait`, the script runs without errors. The same happens if I define the traits first and then the class.

In the first case, the file would look like this:

```
// Working
class MyClass { use MyFirstTrait; }
trait MyFirstTrait { }
```

In the second case like this:

```
// Working

// These two lines can be swapped, the result is the same.
trait MyFirstTrait { use MySecondTrait; }
trait MySecondTrait { } 

class MyClass { use MyFirstTrait; }
```

Why does the behavior change when the traits are nested?

It doesn’t make much sense to me, because in both cases, the used traits are defined later than they are referenced. When the nesting is removed and only single trait is used, there is no problem with the trait being defined after defining the class.

Comment: Looks like PHP bug to me - traits parsing visibility. In not working examples I can see error `Trait 'MyFirstTrait' not found in ...` which should not happen.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Logically, everything you refer to should be defined before you refer to it. There are some exceptions to this though. Taking a step back, a PHP file is interpreted in two steps:

1. Tokenisation and parsing.
2. Runtime execution of the parsed code.

*Generally speaking*, classes will be defined at *runtime*, meaning when the code is executed in the order it is written. Here you must have defined the trait you're going to `use` in another trait *first.* However, some *"simple"* traits and classes can be generated and defined by the parser in the parsing step, so they will be available *before runtime*. That is purely a performance optimisation.

What exactly PHP regards as a "simple class/trait" is not something I would necessarily try to remember or count on, as the capabilities of the parser may expand from one version to another (for instance, at some point simple arithmetic expressions became supported for statements like `static $foo = 4 + 2;`, which was previously a parse error).

Comment: Should not `MySecondTrait` become visible to all objects inside parsed PHP file right after parsing? In my experience declaration of objects within a single PHP file does not matter. Why it does work ONLY with `MyFirstTrait` (MySecondTrait commented out) even if declaration occurs AFTER class declaration? According to your answer it should crash as well, right?

Comment: Likely traits or classes which `use` other traits/classes are *too complex* for the parser to resolve. Simple traits/classes without `use` are resolved at parse time. If you go through each scenario with that in mind, it behaves exactly as expected.

Comment: @deceze Your explanation makes sense. May I ask you for some reference (docs, source code) describing this behavior? Even though it is not something that should be relied upon, I’d like to see it really behaves this way.